# How to initialize log4j2 using log4j.configurationFile in java-vm-args of Java Web Start application (JNLP)

Tags: java, logging, jnlp, log4j2

Log4j2 configuration is initialized in an **EAR** using the JVM argument `log4j.configurationFile` (which is pointing to `log4j2.xml` file in **META-INF** folder of **EAR**) added to the JVM arguments of the application server.

Similarly, I need to initialize log4j2 configuration in a **Java Web Start** application. I can initialize in the code OR by using JVM argument in the application's JNLP file.

`java-vm-args` is the parameter option where I can add `log4j.configurationFile` but I am not aware about how to point to log4j2.xml in this JVM argument which is in a jar.

When I configure from the code, I am seeing below DEBUG statement.

```
DEBUG Initializing configuration XmlConfiguration[location=jar:http://localhost:8080/common/client/application.jar!/log4j2.xml]
```

How can I initialize log4j2 environment in a Java Web start application using JVM argument `log4j.configurationFile` under `java-vm-args` present in JNLP where log4j2.xml is present inside the jar.

**I need this because custom plugins are not getting detected when initializing from the code.**

Please help me.

Comment: in your main method (which is invoked by jws) you can set it by `System.setProperty("log4j.configurationFile", "path to file");` in a static block.

Comment: @guleryuz: Put your answer in the answers section.